# Laravel 8 все маршруты вызывают nginx 404 кроме /

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, apache

У меня проблемы с развертыванием проекта laravel 8 на сервере продукта. После установки, миграции и т.д. все мои маршруты возвращают 404 ошибку nginx, кроме "/".
Вот структура моих папок

```
htdocs
--public
    --app
    --bottstrap
    --public            
    --etc.
```

Я предполагаю, что эта проблема может быть вызвана nginx.conf или apache.conf, но очень трудно понять, где именно проблема.

Моя конфигурация nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    include letsencrypt.conf;
    root  /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    location / {
       
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    }

    access_log off;
    error_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-err;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    #charset    utf-8;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    if ($host ~ www.domain.com) { rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent; }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.comfullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log off;
    #access_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-acc main;
    error_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-err;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;

    set $proxyserver    "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    set $imcontenttype  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set $docroot        "/srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/public";

    index index.php;
    root /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/public;

    # Include parameters common to all websites
    include bx/bitrix.conf;
}
```

и вот мой apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ErrorLog /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-err
    # CustomLog /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-acc combined
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
    </IfModule>

        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                AssignUserID domain.com domain.com
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
                RMode config
                RUidGid domain.com domain.com
                RGroups apache
        </IfModule>

    <Location />
        php_admin_value open_basedir "none"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/srv/www/domain.com/tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/srv/www/domain.com/tmp"
        php_admin_value upload_max_filesize "256M"
        php_admin_value post_max_size "256M"
        php_admin_value memory_limit "512M"
        php_admin_value date.timezone "UTC"
        php_admin_value max_input_vars "10000"
        php_admin_value pcre.recursion_limit "100000"
        php_admin_value realpath_cache_size "4096k"
        php_admin_value mbstring.internal_encoding "utf-8"
        php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload "0"
    php_admin_value opcache.revalidate_freq "0"
        php_admin_value opcache.max_accelerated_files "100000"
        php_admin_value opcache.memory_consumption "256"
        #php_admin_flag short_open_tag "On"
    </Location>

    <DirectoryMatch .*\.svn/.*>
         Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
         Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <DirectoryMatch .*\.hg/.*>
         Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public>
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/managed_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/local_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/stack_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/upload>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/upload/support/not_image>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/images>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/tmp>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        #Nginx should have "proxy_set_header HTTPS YES;" in location
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} =YES
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTPS:on,L]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }` так попробуйте (только отступы верните адекватные), вместо того что в приведенном Вами конфиге

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо за Ваш совет. Ошибка изменилась, теперь 502 и в логах появилась такая ошибка connect() to unix:/usr/sbin/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock failed (20: Not a directory) while connecting to upstream

Comment: Не коннектит к php-fpm сокету.. Вы точно php-fpm используете (тогда надо указывать location для php файлов)? И зачем Вам apache2?

Comment: @InDevX К соажлению приходился работать с тем, что предоставил заказчик. apache я игнорирую, и поставил настройку для nginx которая туда обращается. ПРоверил статус службы php-frpm, она есть и активна, единственное что не могу понять как правильно построить до нее путь

Comment: `location ~ \.php$ { fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; fastcgi_index index.php; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name; include fastcgi_params; }` с рабочего скопировал, в fastcgi_pass сокет свой впишите (возможно, так покажет - `php -i | grep "^listen"`, но это не точно)

Comment: @InDevX Благодарю за совет, попробовал, к сожалению не помогло, все больше и больше возникают мысли, попросить админов выпилить nginx из контейнера и сделать все на старом добром apache